# Avoid space before comma after macro

Tags: manpage, groff

I'm trying to write a manpage by using the `man` macro package of Groff. Specifically, I would like to write some text like the following:

> The daemon can be configured by means of a configuration file. The default
>   location of such file is */etc/trolls.conf*, and this is quite nice.

Desired text proprieties:

- `/etc/trolls.conf` is rendered in Italic
- It is followed by a comma which is *not* in Italic,
- There is no space between `/etc/trols.conf` and the comma.

It is incredibly hard to get a text which satisfies such proprieties!
For example, the following will result in an Italic comma:

```
.SH DESCRIPTION
The daemon can be configured by means of a configuration file. The default
location of such file is
.I /etc/trolls.conf,
and this is quite nice.
```

[image: Result 1]

On the other hand, this second attempt will put a space between `/etc/trolls.conf` and the roman comma:

```
.SH DESCRIPTION
The daemon can be configured by means of a configuration file. The default
location of such file is
.I /etc/trolls.conf
, and this is quite nice.
```

[image: Result 2]

Is there some way to get this to work?

Comment: When writing man pages it is useful to read the man page for the man macros, [groff_man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_man.7.html) where you would also find out about the `\c` character at the end of a line to avoid the space, but your solution using the documented `.IR` macro is indeed the preferred one. Troff was created over 40 years ago, and its longevity says a lot for how well it was crafted.

Comment: @meuh Thanks for the advice. I noticed that the suggested manpage (`groff_man`) is not available on my operating system (Fedora). The package `groff-1.22.3-15.fc28.x86_64` provides the `groff_man` manpage, but it turned out to be [another variant](https://manpage.me/index.cgi?q=groff_man).

Comment: I suppose that is not too surprising, as `\c` is "raw" troff, so I doubt that many people know about it, or any of the weird `\f(` type of inline commands, and perhaps that is just as well. I only know it because I used troff before GNU made it groff and the complexity exploded (judging from some of the other groff man pages). You can read about the original troff typesetting package [here](http://www.troff.org/).  For when computers had 64kbytes of ram.

Comment: @meuh I owe you some respect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This typesetting language is incredibly hard (well, it's also incredibly old), and eventually I solved this by looking at existing manpages!

The solution follows:

```
.SH DESCRIPTION
The daemon can be configured by means of a configuration file. The default
location of such file is
.IR /etc/trolls.conf ,
and this is quite nice.
```

The `.IR` macro will in fact alternate between Italic (`I`) and Roman (`R`), resulting in the correct rendering effect:
[image: good result]